# Module searching for str in text box accepts any match

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following is code which searches a text box, seperates the 4 characters into their respective variables and checks the variable for a match but the error is in the line "If str(user_text) == str(B):" (Line 17). It is never true although it should be, if the == is changed to "in" it allows any amount of the match which isn't safe for the app i'm designing as it would allow anyone to access the account. Any way to help fix this??

```
def Check(user_text):
    global count,  s
    #while looking for line
    fh =open("user_info.txt", "r")
    found = False
    while found == False :
        print("Here")
        s =fh.readline()
        print(s)
        #seperate the words
        if s != "":
                
            N,M,A,B=s.split("~")
            print(f"B ={B}")

            #if its found
            if str(user_text) is str(B):
                found = True
                print ("line Number:", count, ":", s)
                print(found)
                return found
        count+=1
        print(found)
        if count >40:
            return found
    fh.close()
```

Test data includes :
Lol~Nope~JP~232323
John Smith~NOPE~Nope~76231
It should only check the last variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is possible that `N,M,A,B=s.split("~")` the `s` contain the `new line character` such as "/n"

You can try to use `s = s.strip()` to remove that(use it before the split)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you use `readline()` function while reading the lines of your file, it adds a `\n` at the end of the string (check [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)), so as you mentioned, you never get `found` to be `True`.

An easy solution could be replacing the `\n` with blank like this:

```py
N,M,A,B=s.replace("\n", "").split("~")
```